# Need help to convert vb code to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, vb.net-to-c#

I want to crop an image retrieved from the database. I found the following code on the net but it is in vb. I am doing asp.net c# based web page and i have no idea about vb

Can anyone take pain to give me the C# code to the following vb code?

help is highly appreciable and i would be very much thankful to you.

Here is the code:

```
  Dim ImageURL As String = "/Uploads/Gallery/" + ImageID + ".jpg"

        Dim oBitmap As New Bitmap(Server.MapPath(ImageURL))

        Dim Ratio As Integer = oBitmap.Width / 572


        Try

            Dim X1, Y1, X2, Y2, Width, Height As Integer

            Try
                X1 = x1txt.Text
                Y1 = y1txt.Text
                X2 = x2txt.Text
                Y2 = y2txt.Text
                Width = widthtxt.Text
                Height = heighttxt.Text
            Catch
            End Try

            X1 = X1 * Ratio
            Y1 = Y1 * Ratio
            X2 = X2 * Ratio
            Y2 = Y2 * Ratio
            Width = Width * Ratio
            Height = Height * Ratio

            Dim TopLeft As New Point(X1, Y1)
            Dim BottomRight As New Point(CInt(X1) + CInt(Height), CInt(Y1) + CInt(Width))

            Dim BitmapToSave As New Bitmap(oBitmap.Width, oBitmap.Height)

            Dim objGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
            objGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(BitmapToSave)
            objGraphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, 0, 0)

            oBitmap.Dispose()

            BitmapToSave = img.CropImage(BitmapToSave, TopLeft, BottomRight)

            BitmapToSave.Save(Server.MapPath(ImageURL))

            BitmapToSave.Dispose()

        Catch
        End Try
```

Comment: As well as the DeveloperFusion one everybody else is listing, there's a Telerik one: http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this convertor: [Convert VB.NET to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

```
string ImageURL = "/Uploads/Gallery/" + ImageID + ".jpg";

Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(ImageURL));

int Ratio = oBitmap.Width / 572;



try {
    int X1 = 0;
    int Y1 = 0;
    int X2 = 0;
    int Y2 = 0;
    int Width = 0;
    int Height = 0;

    try {
        X1 = x1txt.Text;
        Y1 = y1txt.Text;
        X2 = x2txt.Text;
        Y2 = y2txt.Text;
        Width = widthtxt.Text;
        Height = heighttxt.Text;
    } catch {
    }

    X1 = X1 * Ratio;
    Y1 = Y1 * Ratio;
    X2 = X2 * Ratio;
    Y2 = Y2 * Ratio;
    Width = Width * Ratio;
    Height = Height * Ratio;

    Point TopLeft = new Point(X1, Y1);
    Point BottomRight = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(X1) + Convert.ToInt32(Height), Convert.ToInt32(Y1) + Convert.ToInt32(Width));

    Bitmap BitmapToSave = new Bitmap(oBitmap.Width, oBitmap.Height);

    System.Drawing.Graphics objGraphics = null;
    objGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(BitmapToSave);
    objGraphics.DrawImage(oBitmap, 0, 0);

    oBitmap.Dispose();

    BitmapToSave = img.CropImage(BitmapToSave, TopLeft, BottomRight);

    BitmapToSave.Save(Server.MapPath(ImageURL));

    BitmapToSave.Dispose();

} catch {
}
```

Comment: Presumably that will never compile though, as x1txt.Text etc. will always be a string (not that I'm saying don't use a converter but they 're like google translate a lot of the time)

Comment: But I believe converting code and later correcting it is easier than manually translating it if you don't know source language.

Answer (score 2):

Try this tool to do such things:

- http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

I believe StackOverflow isn't a do-some-work-for-you community!

Answer (score 2):

This is my version, done by hand and C#-orized. Hopefully it has no typos. I've changed the try clause as it could have had zero widths and heights.

```
string imageUrl = "/Uploads/Gallery/" + ImageID + ".jpg";
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(imageUrl));
int ratio = bitmap.Width / 572;
int x1,y1,x2,y2,width,height;

try
{
    x1 = int.Parse(x1txt.Text);
    y1 = int.Parse(y1txt.Text);
    x2 = int.Parse(x2text.Text);
    width = int.Parse(widthtxt.Text);
    height = int.Parse(heightxt.Text);

    x1 *= ratio;
    y1 *= ratio;
    x2 *= ratio;
    y2 *= ratio;
    width *= ratio;

    Point topLeft = new Point(x1,y1);
    Point bottomRight = new Point(x1 + height,y1 + width);
    Bitmap bitmapToSave = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height);

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapToSave))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(bitmap,0,0);
    }

    bitmapToSave = img.CropImage(bitmapToSave,topLeft,bottomRight);
    bitmapToSave.Save(Server.MapPath(imageUrl));
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    // Log
}
```